# Solve the eqation $p^8-p^4=n^5-n$

Tags: number-theory

Solve the equation for primes $p$ and natural numbers $n$ $p^8-p^4=n^5-n$.

For $p=2$ we get $n=3$, bjt for the next 5 prime numbers we get irational numbers. I cant prove (if its true) that there are no more solutions.

Comment: All primes except for $2$ and $3$ are of the form $6k\pm1$.

Comment: @Lucian That's interesting. Do you have a proof?

Comment: @Dylan, a proof that all primes except 2 and 3 are $6k\pm1$? I'm sure that you could work out a proof, if you think about it for a minute.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ok, I figured it out. I've never heard of this before though.

Comment: @Dylan, doing things you've never heard of before is the great kick of Mathematics. Welcome aboard!

Answer (score 3):

if $p\ge 3$ be prime number,then $n\ge 3$,and
$$n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=p^4(p^4-1)$$
Note
$$\gcd{(n,n^2-1)}=\gcd{(n,n^2+1)}=1,\gcd{(n^2-1,n^2+1)}=1\textbf{or}2$$
then have
$$n^2+1\ge p^4$$
so
$$p^4(p^4-1)=n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)\ge n(p^4-2)p^4$$
$$\Longrightarrow p^4-1\ge n(p^4-2)>2(p^4-1)$$
a contradiction

On the other hand,if $p=2$,then we have
$$2^8-2^4=240=3^5-3\Longrightarrow (n,p)=(3,2)$$